# Facebook Login Window Keeps Resizing and Flickering

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have added Facebook Login for my website. The login procedures all function normally. Although, the Login Window seems to expand itself vertically and flickers a lot. You cannot double click on a field to see the saved logins from the browser even, as the window seems to flicker and resize.

[image]

The code I have for the init is as below.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    //SDK loaded, initialize it
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'my-app-id',
        autoLogAppEvents : true,
        status           : true,
        xfbml            : true,
        version          : 'v2.9'
    });
};

//load the JavaScript SDK
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.com/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

//add event listener to login button
function facebookLogin(url) {
    //do the login
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            //user just authorized your app
            myLogin(response.authResponse.accessToken, url);
        } else {
            console.log("Error")
        }
    }, {scope: 'email,public_profile', return_scopes: true});
}
```

Why is this happening? What's the workaround? TIA.

Comment: I even tried adding FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(false); FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 640, height: 480 });

Still no change.

Comment: That sounds like a bug. Have you checked whether you got the same effect on other sites as well? (Any FB.Canvas-methods are of course not going to achieve anything here, those have nothing to do with the login popup, but with the size of the iframe canvas/page tab apps are loaded into.)